# How to fix segmentation fault with two-dimensional nested vectors

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, clion, exit-code, segment

I have written one simple graph Adj Matrix from one Adj List from gitHub .

The first one is Adj list,
Second is Adj matrix.

The first One work well. But the second is wrong with `int Num` which represent the vertices number like the first one `int numOfVertices`.
It seed like the 'int Num' become a read only variable. It crash into `Process finished with exit code 11` .

I have looked for wiki to find "segmentation default", there are 4 reasons , one of them is trying to modify a read only 
variable.

Then I cancel the modify for "Num" in constructor for the Adj Matrix. It work well.

But I don't know why the first one is well but the second is  wrong? And how to solve it? Because I need to modify the value of Num...

The Adj List code

```cpp
#ifndef ALTHGORITHM_GRAPH_ADJ_LIST_H
#define ALTHGORITHM_GRAPH_ADJ_LIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
namespace graph_adj_list {
    template <class dataType>                                 // Type of data vertex will hold
    class Graph {
        int numOfVertices;                                      // number of vertices.
        struct Vertex;                                          // forward declaration of vertex structure
        struct Node {                                           // linkedlist for mapping edges in the graph
            Vertex * vertexPtr;                                   // points to the vertex to which the edge is adjecent
            Node * next;                                          // points to the next edge belonging to same vertex
        };
        enum visitedState{                                      // Enum representing visited state of vertex
            WHITE,                                                // not yet visited
            GRAY,                                                 // being visited
            BLACK                                                 // visited
        };
        struct Vertex {
            visitedState state;                                   // state of vertex, visited/being visited/done
            dataType data;                                        // the template data
            Node * list;                                          // Pointer to all edges (linkedlist)
        };

        std::vector<Vertex> vertices;                           // vector of all vertices.
  //private methods
        Node * getNode( Vertex * );                             // allocate and initialize a newnode for the adj list.
        void insertAtEnd( Node * & , Vertex * );                // insert at the end of adjacency list of vertex.
        void deleteAllAfter( Node * );                          // delete the adjacency list of the vertex.
  public:
        Graph() = default;                                      // Default constructor
        Graph(std::vector<dataType> &); 
        ~Graph();
}
  template <typename dataType>
    typename Graph<dataType>::Node *
    Graph<dataType>::getNode(Vertex * v)                // allocate and initialize a newnode for the adj list.
    {
        Node * newNode = new Node;
        newNode->vertexPtr = v;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        return newNode;
    }
  template <typename dataType>
    void Graph<dataType>::insertAtEnd( Node * & node, Vertex * v)  // insert at the end of adjacency list of vertex.
    {
        Node *newNode = getNode(v);
        if ( node == nullptr ) {
            node = newNode;
        } else {
            Node * temp = node;
            while( temp->next != nullptr ) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = newNode;
        }
    }
    template <typename dataType>
    void Graph<dataType>::deleteAllAfter( Node * node )                  // delete the adjacency list of the vertex.
    {
        Node * nextNode;
        while( node != nullptr ) {
            nextNode = node->next;
            delete(node);
            node = nextNode;
        }
    }


   template <typename dataType>
    Graph<dataType>::Graph(std::vector<dataType> & values)              // Non default constructor, takes a vector of vertices data
            : numOfVertices(values.size()),
              vertices(numOfVertices)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; ++i ) {
            vertices[i].data = values[i];
            vertices[i].list = nullptr;
            vertices[i].state = WHITE;
        }
    }

    template <typename dataType>
    Graph<dataType>::~Graph()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; ++i ) {
            deleteAllAfter(vertices[i].list);
        }
    }
} //end of namespace graph
```

The Adj Matrix code

```cpp
#ifndef ALTHGORITHM_GRAPH_ADJ_MATRIX_H
#define ALTHGORITHM_GRAPH_ADJ_MATRIX_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace graph_adj_matrix {
    template<typename T>
    class Graph {
        int Num ;
        enum visitedState {
            NO_VISIT,
            VISITING,
            VISITED
        };
        struct vertex {
            T data;
            visitedState state;
        };

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix;
        std::vector<vertex> matrix_list;

    public:
        Graph() = default;
        Graph(std::vector<T> &);
        ~Graph();
        void setMatrix(size_t index1, size_t index2);
        void display();
    };


    template<typename T>
    Graph<T>::Graph(std::vector<T> &values) :
                            Num(values.size())
                            ,matrix_list(Num){
        for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0; i < Num; ++i)
        {
            matrix_list[i].data = values[i];
            matrix_list[i].state = NO_VISIT;
        }
        for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0; i < Num; ++i)
            for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type j = 0; j < Num; ++j)
                Matrix[i].push_back(0);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Graph<T>::setMatrix(size_t index1, size_t index2) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Num; ++i) {
            if (i == index1 || i == index2) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < Num; ++j) {
                    if (((i == index1) && (j == index2)) || ((i == index2) && (j == index1))) {
                        Matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Graph<T>::display() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Num; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < Num; j++)
                std::cout << Matrix[i][j] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    Graph<T>::~Graph() {}
}
#endif //ALTHGORITHM_GRAPH_ADJ_MATRIX_H
```

Cpp:

```cpp
#include "Graph_Adj_List.h"
#include "Graph_Adj_Matrix.h"

int main() {


    std::vector<std::string> myVec{"ABC","DEF","GHI","ZZZ"};


    graph_adj_list::Graph<std::string> myGraph(myVec);



    graph_adj_matrix::Graph<std::string> myGraph_matrix(myVec);



}
```

I have debugger the program

```cpp
    graph_adj_list::Graph<std::string> myGraph(myVec);
```

work well.
But the

```cpp
    graph_adj_matrix::Graph<std::string> myGraph_matrix(myVec);
```

stop at

```cpp
#ifndef _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG

template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::push_back(value_type&& __x)
{
    if (this->__end_ < this->__end_cap())
    {
        __RAII_IncreaseAnnotator __annotator(*this);
        __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(),
                                  _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_),
                                  _VSTD::move(__x));
        __annotator.__done();
        ++this->__end_;
    }
    else
        __push_back_slow_path(_VSTD::move(__x));
}
```

A function from vector header Row from 1635 to 1653.
Debugger report this

```cpp
Exception = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
this = {std::_11::vector<int,std::_1::allocator> * |0x0 } NULL
```

When I enter the body that sets the ```Matrix[i].push_back(0)''' It crashes the wrong condition.

Comment: Please attach a debugger and shows us a stack trace along with (your) code that leads up to the crash.

Comment: I am tring to do it.

Comment: If you want us to debug your code you need to provide a [mre]

Comment: I have change my code to minimal code

Comment: @Mr.Weson just FYI you would have gotten a better error / more informative stack trace off the bat if you had used the `vector.at(idx)` method. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Comment: @jkeys Thanks, I have skimmed it. But I can't find the flag resolved . There are a lot bad flags in the question flag label. Such as incomplete.  I skim the help but no result. I just accept the appropriate answer. And I don't have the enough reputation to vote the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Weson Oh sorry resolved is Github terminology, I just meant mark it answered.

Comment: @jkeys OK... I have done it..

Comment: @Mr.Weson Final comment, quote from the docs I cited above: "The function automatically checks whether n is within the bounds of valid elements in the vector, throwing an out_of_range exception if it is not (i.e., if n is greater than, or equal to, its size). **This is in contrast with member operator[], that does not check against bounds**." So it's usually better to use accessors (getter / setter methods) instead of directly indexing into your vectors because the accessors give you additional guarantees and information about where things went / go wrong.

Comment: @jkeys I will Change my program as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just an gues, after short playing around with your code:

> Process finished with exit code 11

Probably could mean that your program encountered *signal 11* (SIGSEGV, aka Segmentation fault)

**My guess:** you forgot to initialize `Matrix`, so `Matrix[i].push_back(0);` causes undefined behaviour and luckily resultet in a segmentation fault.

**Edit:** you can easily initialize the inner vectors with the vector constructor: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>(Num, std::vector<int>(Num));`. This will create a vector with `Num` copies of a vector with `Num` ints.

Comment: Really? I have initialized the `Matrix` as you said, But the problem is still alive.

Comment: churill +1 for finding the root cause of the segfault. @Mr.Weson he was correct that not initializing Matrix would cause a segfault, now extend that concept to another dimension by initializing your vector's vectors. See my answer for more details. And note that if you for whatever reason wanted to have a three dimensional array, say to represent whether a cell is filled or unfilled in a 3d coordinate system, you would have to initialize the interal-most vectors there, too.

Comment: @churill Yes, you are right , My initialization for Matrix is wrong,

Comment: @churill since you have the accepted answer can you add the bit from my post about having to initialize the inner vectors for n-dimensional vectors (where n>1)? (Hopefully that parenthetical saves at least one obsessive computer scientist some angst.)

Answer (score 1):

After having fixed the problem that @churill proposed:

I haven't compiled your code, but I think the problem lies on these lines:

`Matrix[i][j] = 1;`

In this case `Matrix[i]` is a `vector<int>`, but you never reserve capacity for it, so `Matrix[i][j]` is writing to protected / unallocated memory, causing the segfault.

Initialize your "internal" vectors (all `Matrix[i]`) with sufficient capacity and see if that resolves your segfault.

Comment: Yes,I have found the wrong condition through the debugger, Thanks

Comment: comedic timing as always, please mark this question resolved and make sure to upvote anyone who helped you.

Comment: Ok! I will do it.